# Why is my Ajax url found when I test in preview mode, but not when I bring up the page in a url I get not found errors

Tags: mvc, javascript, ajax

Update: this is what my url is trying to resolve to:

/home/about us/api/sitecore/findanaffiliate/getaffiliate/

so here is my Ajax :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#AffiliateList").change(function () {
        var textval = $("AffiliateList :selected").text();
        var selected = $("#AffiliateList :selected").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "api/Sitecore/FindAnAffiliate/GetAffiliate/",
            data: {id: selected},
            content: "html",
            success: function (response) {

                $("#affiliateDetail").empty();
                $("#affiliateDetail").append(response);
            },
            error: function (jqHRX, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqHRX);
                alert(errorThrown);
                alert(textStatus);
            }



            })
    })
</script>
```

when I run the this in Sitecore preview mode everything executes fine, when I type the url into my browser and bring up the page... the java script is being executed, but the url is getting a 400 level error. I am running in the same environment.

here is the controller: findAnAffiliate is NOT being hit unless I am in Preview mode:

```
namespace Website.Controllers
{
    public class FindAnAffiliateController : Controller
    {
        // GET: findAnAffiliate
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult FindAnAffiliate()
        {
            var dataSourceId = RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.DataSource;
            var dataSourceItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dataSourceId);

            var model = new AffiliateViewModel();
            model.title = dataSourceItem.Fields["Title"].Value;
            model.description = dataSourceItem.Fields["Description"].Value;
            model.affiliateList = model.affiliates();

            var selectedItem = model.affiliateList.FirstOrDefault();
            var affiliateItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(selectedItem.Value);

            var affiliateDetail = new Affiliate();

            Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField SponsorLinks = affiliateItem.Fields["Sponsors"];
            var sponsorLinkItems = SponsorLinks.GetItems();

            var count = 0;
            foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item in sponsorLinkItems)
            {


                var ImageLogo = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)item.Fields["Image"];
                var ImageLogoUrl = "";
                if (ImageLogo.Value != "" && ImageLogo != null)
                {
                    ImageLogoUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(ImageLogo.MediaItem);
                }
                var linkName = item.Fields["Link Text"].Value;
                var ImageUrl = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField)item.Fields["Link"];
                var friendlyLinkUrl = ImageUrl.GetFriendlyUrl();

                if (count == 0)
                {
                    affiliateDetail.sponsor1_ImageUrl = ImageLogoUrl;
                    affiliateDetail.sponsor1_linkText = linkName;
                    affiliateDetail.sponsor1_linkUrl = friendlyLinkUrl;
                }

                if (count == 1)
                {
                    affiliateDetail.sponsor2_ImageUrl = ImageLogoUrl;
                    affiliateDetail.sponsor2_linkText = linkName;
                    affiliateDetail.sponsor2_linkUrl = friendlyLinkUrl;
                }

                count++;
            }

            affiliateDetail.title = affiliateItem.Fields["Affiliate Name"].Value;
            var linkUrl =(Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField) affiliateItem.Fields["Affiliate Link"];
            affiliateDetail.linkText = linkUrl.Text != "" ? linkUrl.Text : "No Link Available";
            affiliateDetail.linkUrl = linkUrl.GetFriendlyUrl();
            affiliateDetail.description = affiliateItem.Fields["Description"].Value;
            model.affiliate = affiliateDetail;


            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult GetAffiliate(string id)
        {
            var model = new Affiliate();

            var affiliateItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(id);

            Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField SponsorLinks = affiliateItem.Fields["Sponsors"];
            var sponsorLinkItems = SponsorLinks.GetItems();

            var count = 0;
                foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item in sponsorLinkItems)
                {


                    var ImageLogo = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)item.Fields["Image"];
                    var ImageLogoUrl = "";
                    if (ImageLogo.Value != "" && ImageLogo != null)
                    {
                        ImageLogoUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(ImageLogo.MediaItem);
                    }
                    var linkName = item.Fields["Link Text"].Value;
                    var ImageUrl = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField)item.Fields["Link"];
                    var friendlyLinkUrl = ImageUrl.GetFriendlyUrl();

                if (count == 0)
                {
                    model.sponsor1_ImageUrl = ImageLogoUrl;
                    model.sponsor1_linkText = linkName;
                    model.sponsor1_linkUrl = friendlyLinkUrl;
                }

                if (count == 1)
                {
                    model.sponsor2_ImageUrl = ImageLogoUrl;
                    model.sponsor2_linkText = linkName;
                    model.sponsor2_linkUrl = friendlyLinkUrl;
                }

                count++;
                }


            model.title = affiliateItem.Fields["Affiliate Name"].Value;
            var linkUrl = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField)affiliateItem.Fields["Affiliate Link"];
            model.linkText = linkUrl.Text != "" ? linkUrl.Text : "No Link Available";
            model.linkUrl = linkUrl.GetFriendlyUrl();
            model.description = affiliateItem.Fields["Description"].Value;
            return PartialView(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is the View

```
@model Website.ViewModels.AffiliateViewModel

<div class="container">

    <div class="headline-container">
        <div class="headline-lines"></div>
        <h2 class="text-center">@Model.title</h2>
        <div class="headline-lines"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>@Model.description</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownList("AffiliateList", Model.affiliateList as SelectList, "", new { @id = "AffiliateList", @class = "form-control input-lg" })
        <div id="affiliateDetail">
            <h4>@Model.affiliate.title</h4>
            <p class="affiliateLink"><a href="@Model.affiliate.linkUrl">@Model.affiliate.linkText</a></p>
            <p>@Model.affiliate.description</p>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="@Model.affiliate.sponsor1_ImageUrl">
                <p class="affiliateLink small_p"><a href="@Model.affiliate.sponsor1_linkUrl">@Model.affiliate.sponsor1_linkText</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="@Model.affiliate.sponsor2_ImageUrl">
                <p class="affiliateLink small_p"><a href="@Model.affiliate.sponsor2_linkUrl">@Model.affiliate.sponsor2_linkText</a></p>
            </div> 

        </div>

    </div><!--row-->



</div><!--container-->
      </div><!-- /content container-->    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#AffiliateList").change(function () {
        var textval = $("AffiliateList :selected").text();
        var selected = $("#AffiliateList :selected").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "api/Sitecore/FindAnAffiliate/GetAffiliate/",
            data: {id: selected},
            content: "html",
            success: function (response) {

                $("#affiliateDetail").empty();
                $("#affiliateDetail").append(response);
            },
            error: function (jqHRX, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqHRX);
                alert(errorThrown);
                alert(textStatus);
            }



            })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Are you registering the route via the initialization pipeline?

Comment: no, I am not, is there some documentation on how to do that? please forgive my ignorance

Comment: Code for the route. https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Feature/Accounts/code/Pipelines/RegisterWebApiRoutes.cs.   Config - initialize pipeline .  https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Feature/Accounts/code/App_Config/Include/Feature/Feature.Accounts.config

Comment: I am finding documentation on this ... but I am working with version 8.2 and I was told that api/Sitecore/{Controller}/{Action} is already registered... and why does it work in Preview mode?

Comment: Also, what file is the initialization pipeline in?

Comment: When stuff gets hit ONLY in Preview mode, it is usually an indicator that something hasn't been published correctly. Execute a Smart Publish.

Comment: I agree Mark ... I tried to publish that page, but nothing was published I am going to try a hard publish. Other options of changing pipelines seem dangerous and risky and are not steps in the process of building these ajax commands

Comment: Not just the page. Datasources, templates, related items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way I got this to work ... I did not have to change Route.config.cs, I did create a folder called Pipelines/ and in it I added a "LoadProcessor" which is part of Sitecore. the Load Processor is below:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Website.Pipelines
{
    using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
    using Sitecore.Pipelines;

    // TODO: \App_Config\include\LoadRoutes.config created automatically when creating LoadRoutes class.

    public class LoadRoutes
    {
        public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            Log.Info("Sitecore is starting", this);
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Find an Affiliate api", "api/findanaffiliate/{action}", new { controller = "FindAnAffiliate" });
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Category Search", "api/multiselectandsearch/{action}", new { controller = "MultiSelectAndSearch" });
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Magazine Archive", "api/wildlifemagazinearchive/{action}", new { controller = "WildlifeMagazineArchive" });
        }
    }
}
```

This next xml is created for you, under App_config/Include: this will be added to the Initialization Pipeline

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Website.Pipelines.LoadRoutes,Website" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Then I changed my ajax url :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#AffiliateList").change(function () {
        var textval = $("AffiliateList :selected").text();
        var selected = $("#AffiliateList :selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/FindAnAffiliate/GetAffiliate/",
            data: { id: selected },
            content: "html",
            success: function (response) {

                $("#affiliateDetail").empty();
                $("#affiliateDetail").append(response);
            },
            error: function (jqHRX, textStatus, errorThrown) {


            }



        })

    })
</script>
```

So, notice the url matches the routing in the Load Processor.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend creating a custom route for Ajax functionality that doesn't reside in the Sitecore Shell. From my understanding, using the default route of `/api/Sitecore` only works if you are logged in, which is why it works in preview but not the rest of the time on your site.  Now I'm sure there is a way to change this permission, but you wouldn't want to, since it could open up new security concerns.

To define a custom route you should create a class that defines the route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "FindAnAffiliate/GetAffiliate",
        defaults: new { controller = "FindAnAffiliate", action = "GetAffiliate" }
    );
}
```

And then you would define a patch config, something like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="mvc.Pipelines.LoadRoutes,mvc" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The type should match the namespace and assembly for where you placed your `RegisterRoutes` definition.

This is a helpful resource on the topic:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/mvc/use_mvc_routing

I have added the following to the RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "FindAnAffiliate/GetAffiliate",
        defaults: new { controller = "FindAnAffiliate", action = "GetAffiliate" }
    );
```

Then I created this LoadRoutes.cs

```
 using System.Web.Routing;
namespace Website.Pipelines
{
    using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
    using Sitecore.Pipelines;

    // TODO: \App_Config\include\LoadRoutes.config created automatically when creating LoadRoutes class.

    public class LoadRoutes
    {
        public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            Log.Info("Sitecore is starting", this);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

And this was created under App.Config\Include

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="mvc.Pipelines.LoadRoutes,mvc" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

it is still trying to resolve to /home/AboutUs/api/Sitecore/FindAnAffiliate/GetAffiliate ... which is giving me a 404 error

Comment: Greetings Dylan, thank you so much!! I will review this. Does it matter where I define the RegisterRoutes? and as far the patch, do I add this config file under the same name space, or is there a specific place to place this?

Comment: Hi Dylan ... check out my response below

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel Looks good!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a slash in front of the URL.

url: `api/Sitecore/FindAnAffiliate/GetAffiliate/`,

url: `/api/Sitecore/FindAnAffiliate/GetAffiliate/`,